# How to stop second div from dropping below first div

Tags: html, css

On a 1024x768 screen, I have 2 divs side by side centered on screen.  If I resize the browser window, the second div drops below the first div.  How do I stop this from happening:

http://oshirowanen.x10.mx/

Comment: This may help you with current question and in future: [layout examples](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/). There are some examples of basic layouts.
For example [this one](http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/LayoutGala37.html) may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add the `white-space: nowrap;` style to the container `<body>` and add the `white-space: normal;` style to the two `<div>`s.